# How can I exclude packages with yum-cron on CentOS7?

Tags: centos, yum

On earlier versions of CentOS, and I'm assuming RHEL, you could exclude packages by adding their names to `/etc/sysconfig/yum-cron`.  Putting several newer servers into use now, and I can't find this file on the server.

I'd like to have it skip any database or cluster packages until maintenance windows. As far as I can tell, `/etc/yum/yum-daily.conf` does not have an option to exclude a particular package.

Comment: You should also look at the yum versionlock plugin. This will accomplish the same thing, but without the nasty side effects that exclude can have.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems the same format as before works in the `/etc/yum.conf` file.

I have added the following to the bottom of my `yum.conf` file, and these packages are excluded from all yum updates.

When I do maintenance updates, I have a script that comments out this line before running the yum update, then adds it back before reboot.

```
exclude=pcs corosync pacemaker postgresql jabberd
```